# Plot Results of Each Group after .Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data which I want to create a subplot for each of my different groups based on a column.

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
test = pd.read_csv(r'C:\ETF_PROJECT\etf_grades.csv')

grouped = test.groupby(['$etf_asset_class','ETF_Quintiled_Grades'])['$etf_asset_class'].count().reset_index(name= 'Counts')

df = grouped.set_index(['$etf_asset_class', 'ETF_Quintiled_Grades'])

print(df)
```

The result looks like this:

[DF Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaXtP.png)

What I am trying to do is create a histogram for each $etf_asset_class which shows 5 buckets (1 - 5 based on column called 'ETF_Quintiled_Grades') and the buckets would show the corresponding counts in the 'Counts Column'.

I've provided an example using made up numbers in the dataframe below as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
import random


np.random.seed(300)
rows = 2000
cols = 6
data = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(rows, cols))
index = pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=rows)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=list(al[:cols]))

df=df.groupby(['a','b'])['a'].count()

print(df)
```

Has anyone done anything like this before? Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Without doing the groupby, `ax = pd.crosstab(df.a, df.b).plot(kind='bar', rot=0, figsize=(7, 5))` is probably better. However, it's no really clear what you want as a final rusult.

Comment: `ax = pd.crosstab(df.etf_asses_class, df.ETF_Qintiled_Grades).plot(kind='bar', rot=0, figsize=(7, 5))`